# Add new elements to html page from javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to create an array to hold element styles. When a user clicks a button a new element from the array should be made visible.
This is what i have so far. The button will add a coloured Div. But I'm trying to extend it with an array.

below is my javascript:

```
function addObj()
{
    var newObj = document.createElement('div');

    newObj.style.position = "absolute";
    newObj.style.height = "60px";
    newObj.style.width = "60px";
    newObj.style.top = "60px";
    newObj.style.left = "60px";
    newObj.style.backgroundColor = "blue";


var docBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);

var newElement = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);

var items = new Array();
    items[0] = new Array(100,200,'#FF0000');
    items[1] = new Array(300,400,'#0FFFCC');
    items[2] = new Array(400,500,'#FFFFCC');
    items[3] = new Array(600,200,'#3FFFCC');
    items[4] = new Array(600,200,'#F3FFCC');


for (var i = 0; i > items.length; i++){
    addObj(items[i] [0], items[i] [1]);
//  addObjects(items[i] [0], items[i] [1]);

}

 docBody.appendChild(newObj);

function newObj(leftPos, topPos, color){

    var newObj = addObj(items[i] [0], items[i] [1]);


}

    }
```

This is my html:

```
    <body>
    <button onClick="addObj()">
    Add Object
    </button>




    </body>
```

Comment: Why not just create css classes, and just add/remove the class from the element's `classList`

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking. However I do note a recursive loop in your code. `addObj` is called from within itself, in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the next item on click;

```
var count = 0;  
var items = [
    [100, 200, '#FF0000'],
    [300, 400, '#0FFFCC'],
    [400, 500, '#FFFFCC'],
    [600, 200, '#3FFFCC'],
    [600, 200, '#F3FFCC']
];

function addObj() {
    var target = items[count++];
    if (!target)
        return;

    var newObj = document.createElement('div');

    newObj.style.position = "absolute";
    newObj.style.height = "60px";
    newObj.style.width = "60px";
    newObj.style.left = target[0] + "px";    
    newObj.style.top = target[1] + "px";
    newObj.style.backgroundColor = target[2];

    document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0).appendChild(newObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have refactored code little bit, I donnt functionality but its rendering div control with color.

I suggest you to use jquery which will help you to abstract code a lot.

here is the java script code

function addObj()
{
    var items = new Array();
    items[0] = new Array(100,200,'#FF0000');
    items[1] = new Array(100,400,'#0FFFCC');
    items[2] = new Array(100,600,'#FFFFCC');
    items[3] = new Array(100,800,'#3FFFCC');
    items[4] = new Array(100,1000,'#F3FFCC');


    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        newObj(items[i] [0], items[i] [1], items[i] [2]);
    }        
} 
function newObj(leftPos, topPos, color)
{
    var docBody = document.getElementById("elements");
    var newObj = document.createElement('div');

    newObj.style.position = "absolute";
    newObj.style.height = "60px";
    newObj.style.width = "60px";
    newObj.style.top = topPos;
    newObj.style.left = leftPos;
    newObj.style.backgroundColor = color;

    docBody.appendChild(newObj);
}

Here is your HTML code
<body>
  <div id="elements">
<button onClick="addObj()">Add Object</button>
</div>  
</body>
```